# Evaluate $\int^e_1\frac{xe^x+1}{x}f(e^x+\ln x)\,dx$, where $g'(x)=f(x)$.

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

Suppose $g'(x)=f(x)$ for all $x$. Evaluate
$$\int^e_1\frac{xe^x+1}{x}f(e^x+\ln x)\,dx$$

Also, what are these type of questions called?

Comment: I think the problem type is a substitution.

Comment: Are you sure it's not $\int_0^e (e^x+\frac{1}{x})f(e^x+\ln x)dx$ instead of $\int_0^e (xe^x+\frac{1}{x})f(e^x+\ln x)dx$? The former is much easier than the latter...

Comment: It's actually neither, I edited my question. I probably should have added a parentheses.

Comment: Use [$\LaTeX$](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for formatting while posting anything here.

Comment: Some edits were made to your post. Please proofread to make sure they did not unintentionally changed the intention of your post.

Answer (score 1):

By the Chain Rule and the fact that $f = g'\!$,
\begin{align}
\frac{d}{dx} g(e^x + \ln x) 
&= g'(e^x + \ln x) \bigl( e^x + \tfrac{1}{x} \bigr) \\
&= \frac{xe^x + 1}{x} f(e^x + \ln x).
\end{align}
Therefore, by the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus,
$$
\begin{align}
\int_1^e \frac{xe^x + 1}{x} f(e^x + \ln x) 
&= g(e^x + \ln x) \Big|_1^e \\
&= g(e^e + \ln e) - g(e^1 + \ln 1) \\
&= g(e^e + 1) - g(e).
\end{align}
$$
Without more information, it cannot be simplified further.